# Sockets return no data on virtualbox

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple socket written in python to send a request to the server(Virtualbox Kali Linux) and receive some data from it. It seems like, it is connecting, but receiving no data. Screenshot of behaviour - https://prnt.sc/ragj7q
Here you can see a network config of the Virtualbox[image: Network config of the VirtualBox]
Sever code:

```
import socket


def SocketMon():
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
    serversocket.listen(5)

    while True:
        clientsocket,address = serversocket.accept()
        clientsocket.send(bytes("welcome"),"utf-8")


SocketMon()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",1234))

msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bytes("welcome", "utf-8")`? Or simply `b"welcome"`.

Comment: Oh... Yea. Thank you. I am ever surprised, that it didn't throw any error on that :D But still, no data on the client.

Comment: if client is on normal system and server on `virtualbox` then client can't use IP `127.0.0.1`. Client can use `127.0.0.1` only if it runs on `virtualbox`. Using `ifconfig` on `virtualbox` you should see all network cards with they IPs (value "inet")

Comment: I can access my VirtualBox via port 80 https://prnt.sc/ragsw4

Comment: try client connect to port `80` to see if you get something. But client would have to send data like `GET /` to get answer for www server.

Comment: Well... If I go with port 80 it just hangs up

Comment: client have to send something like `GET / HTTP1.1` to get answer. You would also use `print()` in server to see if it get connection.

Comment: I added - s.send(bytes("GET / HTTP1.1","utf-8"))
And it still hangs up

Comment: By the way, I got interresting response in client (No response in server yet) ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: sorry - it need two new lines at the end `"GET / HTTP1.1\n\n"` - server www use `\n\n` to recognize end of data

Comment: Well, I do get a response - https://prnt.sc/ragzjo

Comment: first I would use `send(b"welcome")` without `"utf-8"` - bytes doesn't need encoding. You would need it in `bytes("welcome", "utf-8")` and it may treats `"utf-8"` in wrong way.

Comment: server www answered in correct way. For port 80 you have port forwading set  without `127.0.01` . Maybe for port `1234` you should set it also without `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Connection forcibly closed by remote host